# Sql Query using group clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my `table` snapshot of sql server.

[image]

i want to write a `sql` `query` , which will return only 3 row, whcih contain max offer from 3 diffrent category.
like in my result there should be 3 different category id, and correspondence to that category's Offer that offer should be maximum in that category

this is my desired output
[image]

as you can see there is 3 diffrent category , and offer belongs to that category is maximum from that category

see

Comment: what did you do so far? and give us a sample of the out put you want to have

Comment: Also, a sample of data and desired output would be nice.

Comment: i mean cat_Id. 
there is cat_Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the Category and the maximum value:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Cat_Id, MAX(Offer) FROM Products GROUP BY Cat_Id
```

But if you want also other fields, you have to use a [rank function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cat_Id ORDER BY Offer DESC) AS RowNumber,
        Cat_Id, Offer, Name, Model
     FROM Products) AS T
WHERE RowNumber=1
```

Comment: could add top 3 and order by max (offer) desc

Comment: sir that was just sample . 
i also want to retrive all the column data. not only cat_id & offer .
i want to Pro_id,Name, Discription e.tc.
can't i use here *

Comment: @AmitKumar Here it is.

Answer (score 0):

There 2 different approach to your query:

```
select * from (
select *, dense_rank() over( order by ct desc) t from (
select *, max(Offer) over (partition by cat_id) ct from Products
) o)o2 where t<3
```

or

```
select * from Products s inner join (
select top 3 Cat_id, max(Offer) max_offer from Products
group by Cat_id
order by max_offer desc) o on o.Cat_id=s.Cat_id
```

Comment: this query returing all the records from table